# over-riding !important style with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have an element with class

```
display:none !important;
```

But I want to use jquery to show the element

```
$('#returning_customer_check').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#returning_customer').show();
        $('#new_customer').hide();
        customer = 1;
    } else {
        $('#returning_customer').hide();
        $('#new_customer').show();
        customer = 0;       
    }
});
```

This is not working, is there a way to over-ride the css with the jquery?

Comment: It can be overridden with a more specific `!important` rule.

Answer (score 6):

`.show()` converts to `style="display:block"`.

Therefore short-term fix you can do:

```
$(this).attr("style", "display:block !important");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ew7hpp6w/

However I would recommend removing the `!important` altogether. It's clearly not being used correctly if you're finding a more *important* reason to remove it.

Comment: Agreed with Curt! The !important declaration is supposed to be used for rules that take precedence over normal declarations. If you are overwriting a rule, than it does not warrant the !important declaration. Instead, use more specific selectors and reserve !important for things that are more... important... =)

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably want to remove the offending class:

```
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).removeClass('badClass');
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Problem with this is it might not be a class. Could be `#returning_customer { display:none !important }` or `div { display:none; }`. But I agree the `!important` declaration has got to go.

Comment: It clearly states "class" in the question, though I did doubt whether that's what the OP actually meant.